# Custom Slider - How To Automatically Go Through Each Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am fairly new to Javascript and recently built the following slider: http://cpointweb.com/dtv/ (if you hover over blue boxes, content on the left changes)

Here is the code:

```
            function changeSlider(header, html, img) {
               var rightHtml = '<h2>' + header + '</h2><p>' + html + '</p>';
               var slider = '<img src="' + img + '" />';

                $('.right').fadeOut('fast', function(){
                    $(this).html(rightHtml).fadeIn('slow');
                });
                $('.slider-image').fadeOut('fast', function(){
                    $(this).html(slider).fadeIn('slow');
                });


            }

            $('#1').mouseover(function() {
            changeSlider("Dossani Turnage & Van Hoose Thanks You!", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p><p>Testing Another Line","img/slider-one.jpg");
            });

            $('#2').mouseover(function() {
            changeSlider("With Dossani, Turnage & Van Hoose...", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p><p>Testing Another Line","img/slider-two.jpg");;
            });

            $('#3').mouseover(function() {
            changeSlider("With Dossani, Turnage & Van Hoose...", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p><p>Testing Another Line","img/slider-three.jpg");

            });

            $('#4').mouseover(function() {

            changeSlider("With Dossani, Turnage & Van Hoose...", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p><p>Testing Another Line","img/slider-four.jpg");

            });

            $('#5').mouseover(function() {
            changeSlider("With Dossani, Turnage & Van Hoose...", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p><p>Testing Another Line","img/slider-five.jpg");

            });

            $('#6').mouseover(function() {
            changeSlider("With Dossani, Turnage & Van Hoose...", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p><p>Testing Another Line","img/slider-6.jpg");
            });
```

Is it possible to rotate through each of these with my current code? I know of WindowTimers.setInterval() but am not sure how I would execute that with my current code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put your header, html and img strings in an array.

```
var dataArray = [["header", "html", "img"], ["header2", "html2", "img2"]];
```

set a time variable and a counter,

```
var loopTime = 2000;
var count = 0;
```

then use setTimeout to call a function that increments a counter, then calls your changeSlider function.

```
$(function(){
    Loop();
});

function Loop(){
    changeSlider(dataArray[count][0], dataArray[count][1], dataArray[count][2]);
    count++;
    if(count >= dataArray.length) count = 0;
    setTimeout(Loop, loopTime);
}

function changeSlider(header, html, img) {
    var rightHtml = '<h2>' + header + '</h2><p>' + html + '</p>';
    var slider = '<img src="' + img + '" />';

    $('.right').fadeOut('fast', function(){
        $(this).html(rightHtml).fadeIn('slow');
    });
    $('.slider-image').fadeOut('fast', function(){
        $(this).html(slider).fadeIn('slow');
    });
}
```

update;

if you were to put a data-id property on your blue boxes you could then use it to index the array when you do your mouseover calls

`<img id="1" data-id="0"/>`

```
$('#1').mouseover(function() {
    var id = parseInt($(this).data("id"));
    changeSlider(dataArray[id][0], dataArray[id][1], dataArray[id][2]);
}
```

UPDATE:

I have made a JSFiddle showing this looping working here -> [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2cneebth/)

Comment: Am I putting the array inside the function I created? As well as the time variable/counter?

Comment: i would put the array and the counter and timer variables outside everything at the start of your script. this makes them globally accessible to all functions on the page.

Comment: `dataArray` is hash it should be `dataArray = [["header", "html", "img"]]` though i would use `dataArray = [{'header': "header", 'content': "html", 'image': "img"}];` personally well unless you are planning on using `changeSlider.apply()` ....

Comment: sorry that was my typo it should be [ [] ] not { [] } to declare the array

Comment: Thanks for that. How would I go about calling that loop then? Do I apply it to each .mouseover() I have (all 6) or is there a different way I should be doing that?

Comment: Yes, I would change all 6 mouseover functions, and the loop will start automatically once the page has finished loading, as the $(function(){}() calls the SetTimeout.

Comment: Hmm, I think I'm lost. What am I changing the mouseover functions to exactly if that is where I am defining the content? Sorry ahead of time, I feel like you are doing it all for me, but I am trying to learn! A lot to wrap my head around for being so new.

Comment: the point is that by putting the content in the array, you take it out of the mouseover functions. This is so you avoid duplicating the content in the page as you will be using the content in two places; the loop function(passing it into the changeslider function) and the mouseover function(again passing it into the changeslider function). By bringing the content out, it appears only once and and any edits you make to it need only be done once, and avoid duplicating work and/or errors.

Comment: Figured it out! Got it working at http://cpointweb.com/dtv/

Thanks so much for the help. If I wanted to change the class on each box when it is active how would I accomplish that with the code I have? Basically want to indicate which slider they are on.

I know of the function. Just wondering how I implement it into the current code?

Comment: $("whatever").addClass("testClass"); Also I updated my answer with a demo Fiddle of the looping. ALSO - change the inital value of COUNT to 1 which will avoid showing the 1st set of data twice ;)

Comment: But with there being different ID's, how would the loop know of which id to change the class? I feel like if I apply it withint he mouseover, it will only work when I hover over it with the mouse? 

or am I just thinking about this wrong?

Comment: But with there being different ID's, how would the loop know of which id to change the class? I feel like if I apply it withint he mouseover, it will only work when I hover over it with the mouse? or am I just thinking about this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
                var dataArray = ["header", "html", "img"];
                var loopTime = 2000;
                var count = 0;

            function changeSlider(header, html, img) {
               var rightHtml = '<h2>' + header + '</h2><p>' + html + '</p>';
               var slider = '<img src="' + img + '" />';


                $('.right').fadeOut('fast', function(){
                    $(this).html(rightHtml).fadeIn('slow');
                });
                $('.slider-image').fadeOut('fast', function(){
                    $(this).html(slider).fadeIn('slow');
                });

                $(function(){
                    SetTimeout(Loop, loopTime);
                });

                function Loop(){
                    changeSlider(dataArray[count][0], dataArray[count][1], dataArray[count][2]);
                    count++;
                    if(count >= dataArray.length) count = 0;
                    setTimeout(Loop, loopTime);
                }
            }

            $('#1').mouseover(function() {
            changeSlider("Dossani Turnage & Van Hoose Thanks You!", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p><p>Testing Another Line","img/slider-one.jpg");

            });

            $('#2').mouseover(function() {
            changeSlider("With Dossani, Turnage & Van Hoose...", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p><p>Testing Another Line","img/slider-two.jpg");;
            });

            $('#3').mouseover(function() {
            changeSlider("With Dossani, Turnage & Van Hoose...", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p><p>Testing Another Line","img/slider-three.jpg");

            });

            $('#4').mouseover(function() {

            changeSlider("With Dossani, Turnage & Van Hoose...", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p><p>Testing Another Line","img/slider-four.jpg");

            });

            $('#5').mouseover(function() {
            changeSlider("With Dossani, Turnage & Van Hoose...", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p><p>Testing Another Line","img/slider-five.jpg");

            });

            $('#6').mouseover(function() {
            changeSlider("With Dossani, Turnage & Van Hoose...", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p><p>Testing Another Line","img/slider-6.jpg");
            });
```

Comment: no, the $(function(){}) is the default page ready function and both it and the Loop function should be outside your changeSlider function